# Windows Task Scheduler Last Run Result (0xF6)

Tags: python, windows-task-scheduler

What does Last Run Result (0xF6) mean?

- I scheduled the Task Scheduler to run a *pythonw.exe with the arguments pointed to the *.py file.
- User account is set for an admin account
- Run whether user is logged on or not
- Run with the highest privileges
- Configured for Windows 10

I can't find a reference to this in a google search. Whatever is happening via the Task Scheduler I can't really tell because the python script does not finish-- meaning I can't read the log file to check how far it got or if it ran into any errors. If I run the script without the Task Scheduler it completes successfully.

[image]

[image]

Comment: use pythonw.exe to run your task rather than python.exe . Use pro python environment to run your task. follow this [link](https://community.esri.com/t5/python-questions/last-run-result-message-0xf6-when-trying-to-run-a/td-p/306098) to read more on this

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of that thread. That is where I got the idea to use ArcGIS Pro to schedule a geoprocesing tool to run. Pro actually runs the Task Scheduler in the background, and it uses *.pythonw.exe. I'm looking for an explanation of 0xF6.

Comment: The script actually ran over the weekend albeit it didn't complete successfully, so I was able to check the logged print statements. There was an error in the script. I fixed this then reset the scheduler and it ran successfully. So, maybe 0xF6 is telling me there is an error in the script.